# Quantum Theory Texts Advocating Specific Interpretations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, soft-question, quantum-interpretations

I'm looking for comprehensive textbooks or monographs on quantum mechanics that inherently advocate specific interpretations. I've found a few over the course of time such as [Ballentine's](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9038#t=aboutBook) or [Dürr's](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b99978) books which advocate the Ensemble Interpretation and the Bohmian Interpretation respectively. Most typical texts favour the Copenhagen Interpretation so there's no shortage of those either. However, I've not found many formal texts or lectures online detailing the Everettian interpretation among some others which call for some subtleties in the formalism itself. Can someone point me to relevant resources?

Comment: Slightly related, the book "What is real ?" by Adam Becker goes into the history of quantum mechanics from the point of view of the measurement problem; There is in particular a detailed history and explanation of the various interpretations ! I highly recommend it

Comment: I'm not sure that it advocates for a *particular* interpretation, but it *does* take some biting shots at some interpretations (this is decidedly *not* a many-worlds text), but Asher Peres' "Quantum Theory: Concepts and Methods" is exceptional. An insightful and deep and somewhat rigorous book from one of the intellectual godfathers of quantum information.

Comment: From the text: "The purpose of this book is to clarify the conceptual meaning of quantum theory, and to explain some of the mathematical methods that it utilizes. This text is not concerned with specialized topics such as atomic structure, or strong or weak interactions, but with the very foundations of the theory. This is not, however, a book on the philosophy of science. The approach is pragmatic and strictly instrumentalist. This attitude will undoubtedly antagonize some readers, but it has its own logic: quantum phenomena do not occur in a Hilbert space, they occur in a laboratory."

Comment: Also: "Some authors state that the last stage in this chain of measurements involves “consciousness,” or the “intellectual inner life” of the observer, by virtue of the "principle of psycho- physical parallelism.” Other authors introduce a wave function for the whole Universe. In this book, I shall refrain from using concepts that I do not understand." Finally, it's one of the few "introductory" quantum text books that covers Bell's theorem *and* the Kochen-Specker theorem and detail.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112968/2451 and links therein.

Comment: "The emergent multiverse" by David Wallace is about the Everett interpretation. See also https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2832 https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033 https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.02328 https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02048